# How do I delete this read only file?

Tags: file-system, root-access

In order to enable USB mass storage mode, I placed a file in the `/system/etc/init.d/` directory. My situation has changed, and now I want to remove that file. I know it is safe to remove because I put it there.

However, I can not delete it. I have a rooted phone, and I have tried using ES File Explorer and also `su` mode in a command line emulator, but every time I try to delete it, I get an error that says `rm can't remove 'MassStorage': Read-only file system`.

How do I delete this file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `su`, do this :

```
# mount -o remount,rw /system
```

You will now be able to delete it.

---

As said in comments, don't forget to

```
# mount -o remount,ro /system
```

or just reboot when you have finished. :)

Comment: And don't forget to do `mount -o remount,ro /system` afterwards.

Comment: Or reboot immediately... :)